# Files diff in Jenkins with ClearCase

Tags: c++, jenkins, diff, clearcase

I have successfully integrated "ClearCase Plugin" with my ClearCase system. The only thing which is not working yet is the Changes window. It lists all the changes as expected for example:

```
testMain.cpp@@/main/5  - create version
tetsHeader.h@@/main/3  - create version
```

But there is no option to see the change. From another company, I remember that these changes were links pointing to a diff which shows the changes graphically. Do you have some idea how can I configure this?

Comment: @localhost: please avoid using `code` formatting for things that aren't code.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot configure it through Jenkins, you can at least fall back to the CLI ( command-line interface)

```
cd /path/to/view
cleartool diff -graph -pred testMain.cpp@@/main/5
```

Comment: Yes that is a some solution, thanks for it! But still it would be much comfortably to use Jenkins.

Comment: @Faron I agree. I am simply not aware of that kind of integration.